# Can I split a string at multiple hex characters in javascript with .split method?

Tags: javascript, split, hex, character

I have a string containing SOH, STX and ETX characters which I need to split into parts. I tried this using the .split() method on the string but it only works with a single hex character, not when I specify all 3.

A string example is:

```
"\x01header\x02maintext\x03trailer"
string.split(\x01) works
```

with regular printable characters you can split at multiple characters so I tried the same thing with hex characters:

```
string.split(/\x01/)works
```

but then:

```
string.split(/\x01x02x03/) does not work
string.split(/\x01 x02 x03/) does not work
string.split(/\x01,x02,x03/) does not work


string = '\x01header\x02maintext\x03trailer'
string.split(\x01);
console.log(string[1]);      // 'header\02maintext\03trailer'

string.split(/x01/);  
console.log(string[1]);      // 'header\02maintext\03trailer'

string.split(/x01x02x03/);   // expect string[1] 'header'
                             //        string[2] 'maintext'
                             //        string[3] 'trailer'

console.log(string[1]);  // prints 'undefined'
console.log(string[2]);  // prints 'undefined'
console.log(string[3]);  // prints 'undefined'
```

Is it not possible to do this with the split() method in javascript?

Comment: You're looking for `/[\x01\x02\x03]/`. This is [basic regular expression syntax.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Thank you, I thought the '/ /' were the delimiters. I'm not an experienced javascript programmer.

Comment: They `//` indeed are the delimiters. the `[]` denote a character class. `/[ab]/` matches "a" and "b", whereas `/ab/` matches "ab".